# How to make a plug and play WPF app create a SQL database?

Tags: c#, sql-server, wpf

I'm currently learning WPF with the goal of making a simple app for a friend. This app will make use of a database and the PC were it will run *won't be connected to the internet*.

I know how to make a simple database using the server management studio, and how to connect to it in my code. But so far, all tutorials/docs I've seen only talk about making use of a database in my pc, but in the case when I finish said app, how I go about setting all of this up in his (or any other)?

The end goal is for the app to be 'plug and play' and that the database files can be easily backed up.

I don't expected a step by step process! Just some direction for where to look for would be more than enough... thank you.

Comment: Set up a SQLite DB. It consists of a single file. You can ship that file with your app. Alternatively you can use SQL Server Express LocalDB which is harder to set up during installation of your app

Comment: „Setting all of this up“ is the job of a setup application - there are a lot of tutorials how to build a setup which will create a database and install your (wpf) app

Comment: _”obtuse”_ - do you mean _obscure_?

Comment: SQLITE is good but not for large solutions

Comment: Unfortunately this is the wrong site for general system design questions. SO is for specific technical issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an SQLite DB, can be part of the App